# constructing a projection onto a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$. Given any linear subspace $S$ we can choose a complement of $T$ in $V$, i.e. $\mathbb{C}^n=S \oplus T$ and we can subsequently define a projection $\pi_S:\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow S$ given by $x=x_S+x_T \mapsto x_S$, where $x_S,x_T$ are the unique components of $x$ in $S,T$ respectively.

Now let $f_1,\cdots,f_k$ be elements of $\mathbb{C}[y_1,\cdots,y_n]$. These polynomials define a variety $V$, i.e. the zero set of the ideal that they generate. Question: is there a way to define a projection $\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow V$ in a similar manner as we did for linear subspaces? Alternatively, is there any way of defining a surjective map $\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow V$ given the polynomials $f_1,\cdots,f_k$?

Edit: From the comments, i understand that this is not possible in general. Then, under what conditions can we obtain such a surjection? Is there an approximation theory of how close a point of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is to the variety of interest?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Can you explain why is this the case?

Comment: You learn more when you look at some simple examples first. After all, it fails for almost all varieties.

Comment: We immediately run into a problem when $V$ is disconnected.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you please give me a starting point of how one would even begin constructing such a projection (irrespectively of the fact that this construction would later fail). Any answer that adds any insight is very welcome.

Comment: Dear Manos -- I don't know how. My first observation was that even in the simplest cases, say $n=1$ and $V$ consists of two distinct points, there is no clear way to project continuously onto both of them. Secondly, projection onto a subspace is intricately linked with the vector space operations on $\mathbb C^n,$ while nonlinear polynomials do not behave nicely with respect to these operations.

Comment: @Andrew: If you make this comment into an answer, i will upvote it.

Comment: @Manos: the question whether there exists a surjective morphism $\mathbb C^n\to V$ is extremely subtle and interesting:+1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I am extremely interested in studying under what conditions such a surjective morphism exists. Any insight towards this direction will be upvoted :) Bibliographic references are also extremely welcome.

Comment: Dear Manos, I advise you to ask your question on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions), duly acknowledging that you first asked it here two days ago (and providing a link).

Comment: Yes the question whether there is a surjective morphism from $\mathbb{C}^n$ is subtle, but Manos asked for a *projection*.

Comment: From a layman perspective, perhaps locally one can obtain the tangent plane at a point P on the variety and project using the normal direction to a point on V near P?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me just explain why the question is subtle and interesting as said Georges.

An obvious necessary condition to have a surjective map $\mathbb C^n \to V$ is $V$ is irreducible because the image of an irreducible topological space is irreducible. Also you can replace $V$ by the associated reduced variety, this doesn't change the existence of a surjective map from $\mathbb C^n$. So we suppose $V$ is an integral affine algebraic variety.

Now another more serious necessary condition is that the function field of $V$ must be the function field of a (smooth projective) *unirational variety* $\overline{V}$ (by definition this means there exists a dominant rational map $\mathbb P^n --\to \overline{V}$, or equivalently, a dominant morphism from an open subset of $\mathbb P^n$ to $\overline{V}$. This is because the surjevtive map $\mathbb C^n\to V$ induces a dominant rational map from $\mathbb P^n$ to any smooth projective variety birational to $V$. Unirational varieties are  rationally connected. There is a vast litterature on this subject (a good starting point is Kollar's "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" or Debarre's "Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry").

Suppose $\mathbb C(V)$ is the function field of a unirational smooth projective variety $\overline{V}$, can one decide whether there is a surjective map from $\mathbb C^n$ ? This in my opinion is a hard question.

If $\dim V=1$, then unirational implies rational by Lüroth's theorem. And it is then easy to see that there exists a surjective map $\mathbb C^n\to V$ if and only if $V$ is a (possibly singular, but integral) rational projective curve minus a smooth point. But in higher dimension, even when $V$ is a smooth surface, I don't know a characterization (though $V$ then must be rational).

Remark: the usual definition of unirational requires a dominant rational map from $\mathbb P^{\dim V}$. One can replace $\dim V$ by any integer $n$ by  Debarre, 4.2(2).

A weaker and purely algebraic question is when a $\mathbb C$-algebra of finite type is contained in a polynomial ring $\mathbb C[y_1, \dots, y_n]$.

Comment: Dear QiL, I'm happy that you confirm that the problem is difficult. I had indeed thought of irreducibility and unirationality as obstructions, but even rationality is not sufficient: a subalgebra of $\mathbb C[y_1,y_2,...,y_n]$ has  only $\mathbb C^*$ as regular invertible functions and this gives a new obstruction. For example it is impossible to map surjectively $\mathbb C^2$ onto its (rational!) subvariety $xy=1$ since the latter has $x$ as non-constant invertible function.Thus a source of impossibilities is suitable deletion of divisors of rational functions from complete varieties.

Comment: [Dear QiL, I'm sure  you know the above, but I wanted it to be stated explicitly for potential other users, as a complement to your remark that you may delete only **one** point from a complete rational curve if you want it to have the required property.]

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, thanks for the comments ! As for "minus one point", I mixed two phrases saying the same thing.

Comment: @QiL'8: a nitpick --- you wrote "Unirational varieties are uniruled and the later are rationally connected", but I don't think that's what you meant...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: thanks, I will edit.

Comment: Thanks QiL'8. It will take some time until i understand your answer, i might be back :)